# zip files won't open in Mac OS

Tags: php, zip

Here, I am using PHP ZipArchive to give website users to combine a pdf file and some folders into a zip file, and then download them. It works perfectly on the Windows, linux computer I'm running it on. But if I download the files using my Mac the files will not unzip, double clicking creates a cpgz file.

Can you please how can I resolve this issue on MAC?

Comment: Mac OSx is a big Issue itself :-D
Try to to that from the terminal

Answer (score 0):

You can use [The Unarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html) to unzip zip files on mac

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Here, I can not say to my clients to install some software to open the zip file. Can you help me in the coding level, if is there a chance to solve this issue by coding?

Comment: This worked for me and was able to open the zip file

Comment: The Mac Finder has a built-in feature to unzip and gunzip files. It works fine normally, EXCEPT for .gz files created by PHP for some reason. The problem is about why gz files created by PHP cause Mac to be unable to gunzip. The answer isn't just to install 3rd party software and gunzip it that way. The Finder should be able to do it. PHP is doing something weird. That's the problem to solve.

Answer (score -1):

Try to unzip them from the command line. Open up a terminal, navigate to the folder where the zip is located and type `unzip <zip_file>`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion... But here I want to open the zip file as other windows systems. So do I need to change any thing in the coding part to open the zip in the mac...

Comment: a zip file is simply an archive. It is the file browser that allows you to browse into the archive by making it look like a regular folder. I am not sure if it is possible to do that in mac. What I suggest, however will always work - after you unzip the archive it is just a regular folder(or file).

Comment: The Mac Finder has a built-in feature to unzip and gunzip files. It works fine normally, EXCEPT for .gz files created by PHP for some reason. The problem is about why gz files created by PHP cause Mac to be unable to gunzip.

Answer (score -1):

If you zipped it then obviously you need to use some 3rd party unarchiver to unzip it.I face the similar problem before on Mac.After installing unzipper the issue is solved.Mac does not have that by default.

Comment: Mac DOES have that by default. This problem only occurs with some files gzipped by PHP.